# MATLAB/Octave interpolation of table (N dependent over M independent) variables

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have the given table:

```
AoA  vel    CDa        CLa       CSa          Cmxa       Cmya        Cmza
```

-40  5    1.14668   -1.13299     0.007386    -0.00189    0.00032    -0.06785
-30  5    0.792945  -1.05145     0.001173     0.000308  -0.00066    -0.05284
-20  5    0.46091   -0.9383      0.004354    -0.00228   -0.00047    -0.03891
-10  5    0.176381  -0.70155    -0.0037       0.000787   2.33E-07   -0.02382
 10  5    0.189115  1.388965    -0.00634      0.002562  -0.00117     0.024032
 15  5    0.309158  1.551853    -0.00271      5.05E-05   0.000825    0.033537
 20  5    0.640063  1.489591    -0.02716      0.006253  -0.00117     0.038003
 30  5    0.843689  1.382815     0.004803    -0.00204   -0.00216     0.050888
 45  5    1.435123  1.337931    -0.01323      0.001252  -0.00139     0.069426

-40 10    1.135769  -1.12232     0.008136    -0.00338    0.000516   -0.13411
-30 10    0.786587  -1.04173     0.000678     0.001555  -0.00207    -0.10408
-20 10    0.454954  -0.93194     0.002149    -0.00573   -0.00102    -0.07623
-10 10    0.17226   -0.70207    -0.0055       0.001301   0.000137   -0.04808
 10 10    0.185599   1.40734    -0.0057       0.001352  -0.00197     0.047792
 15 10    0.302297   1.554765   -0.00804      0.000129  -0.00238     0.068301
 20 10    0.635433   0.917047   -0.02498      0.007075  -0.00257     0.089213
 30 10    0.840859   1.379861    0.008731    -0.00259   -0.00295     0.101972
 45 10    1.600783   1.628605   -0.00913      0.000973  -0.0029      0.073734

-40 15    1.134235  -1.12156     0.008302    -0.00298    0.00131    -0.13368
-30 15    0.78341   -1.0394      0.0019       0.001564  -0.00192    -0.10364
-20 15    0.456106  -0.93554     0.003156    -0.00523   -0.00066    -0.07602
-10 15    0.17026   -0.69772    -0.0069       0.00247    0.000491   -0.04811
 10 15    0.183753   1.411952   -0.00514      0.001282  -0.0019      0.047676
 15 15    0.306336   1.572716   -0.02108     -0.00823   -0.00079     0.068636
 20 15    0.446206   1.49619    -0.02127      0.004692  -0.00195     0.075722
 30 15    0.794182   1.287936    0.024425    -0.00247   -0.00354     0.119258
 45 15    1.564058   1.411367   -0.01153      0.00088   -0.0027      0.158261

-40 20    1.130857  -1.11942     0.011118    -0.00251    0.001287   -0.13325
-30 20    0.783355  -1.03969     0.001792     0.001849  -0.00195    -0.10357
-20 20    0.453382  -0.93397     0.004538    -0.00527   -0.00116    -0.07611
-10 20    0.169203  -0.70222    -0.00304      0.001263  -0.00043    -0.04776
 10 20    0.182575   1.414132   -0.00465      0.001476  -0.00181     0.047619
 15 20    0.302945   1.557986   -0.02611     -0.01088   -0.00131     0.069002
 20 20    0.441594   1.667185   -0.03727      0.018395  -0.001       0.085187
 30 20    0.833129   1.367756    0.021856    -0.00202   -0.00372     0.100927
 45 20    1.414648   1.322671   -0.01084      0.000713  -0.00222     0.137053

-40 25    1.130254  -1.11854     0.011035    -0.0026       0.001291 -0.13307
-30 25    0.78033   -1.03801     0.006084     0.001668    -0.00065  -0.10342
-20 25    0.454824  -0.93126    -3.40E-06    -0.00521     -0.00019  -0.07559
-10 25    0.167459  -0.69818    -0.0036       0.002762     0.000251 -0.04732
 10 25    0.181822   1.416205   -0.00467      0.001572    -0.00181   0.047616
 15 25    0.307287   1.595218   -0.01342     -0.00625     -0.00398   0.072986
 20 25    0.449001   1.491301   -0.03155      0.01809     -0.00051   0.074918
 30 25    0.853412   1.258704    0.017987    -0.00277     -0.00635   0.089384
 45 25    1.543683   1.460518   -0.01509     -0.00111     -0.00411   0.14807

-40 30    1.125591  -1.11304     0.00975     -0.0033       0.001251 -0.13249
-30 30    0.780225  -1.0392      0.007942     0.002208    -0.00092  -0.10343
-20 30    0.453074  -0.9373      0.002856    -0.00568     -0.00058  -0.07605
-10 30    0.166888  -0.7011     -0.00378      0.002011     6.89E-05 -0.04708
 10 30    0.181113   1.41787    -0.00429      0.001623    -0.00172   0.04744
 15 30    0.309359   1.560654   -0.01769     -0.00408     -0.00315   0.073177
 20 30    0.424315   1.507518   -0.0368       0.019651    -0.0007    0.076681
 30 30    0.829189   1.368019    0.008733    -0.00308     -0.00554   0.100652
 45 30    1.416077   1.324257   -0.01235     -0.00132     -0.00327   0.137079

-40 35    1.128033  -1.11649     0.009527    -0.00154      0.000553 -0.06634
-30 35    0.781222  -1.04085     0.003488     0.001143    -0.00094  -0.05175
-20 35    0.452797  -0.93978     0.003031    -0.0029      -0.0004   -0.03791
-10 35    0.16714   -0.70461     6.22E-05     0.000711    -0.00057  -0.02364
 10 35    0.180499   1.418791   -0.00459      0.000791    -0.0009    0.02378
 15 35    0.303655   1.545379   -0.01416     -0.00088     -0.0001    0.035761
 20 35    0.477813   1.317009   -0.03607      0.011042     0.000731  0.036779
 30 35    0.833212   1.306725   -0.01089     -0.00047     -0.00033   0.048257
 45 35    1.387943   1.286388   -0.01112     -0.00306     -0.00334   0.060734

-40 40    1.130903  -1.12077     0.008338    -0.00266    0.001092    -0.13321
-30 40    0.779686  -1.03895     0.007888     0.002269  -0.00089     -0.10334
-20 40    0.450783  -0.93033     0.000821    -0.00456    0.00064     -0.07527
-10 40    0.166252  -0.70388    -0.00162      0.001372  -0.00043     -0.04719
 10 40    0.180017   1.420129   -0.00468      0.001581  -3.60E-05     0.047408
 15 40    0.302535   1.530176   -0.00861      0.005485  -0.00278      0.071903
 20 40    0.447166   1.489379   -0.03367      0.020146   0.003072     0.074659
 30 40    0.831837   1.375903   -0.01245      7.12E-05  -0.00282      0.10027
 45 40    1.41966    1.329288   -0.00866     -0.00745   -0.00655      0.137312

Independent variables: $AoA$, $vel$

Dependent variables: $CDa$, $CLa$, $CSa$, $Cmxa$, $Cmya$, $Cmza$

So far I have the solution for the any of dependent variables, e.g. for $CDa$:

```
AoA = [-40, -30, -20, -10, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45]; % 9 elements
vel = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]; % 8 elements
CDa = [1.14668, 0.792945, 0.46091, 0.176381, 0.189115, 0.309158, 0.640063, 0.843689, 1.435123,
       1.135769, 0.786587, 0.454954, 0.17226, 0.185599, 0.302297, 0.635433, 0.840859, 1.600783,
       1.134235, 0.78341, 0.456106, 0.17026, 0.183753, 0.306336, 0.446206, 0.794182, 1.564058,
       1.130857, 0.783355, 0.453382, 0.169203, 0.182575, 0.302945, 0.441594, 0.833129, 1.414648,
       1.130254, 0.78033, 0.454824, 0.167459, 0.181822, 0.307287, 0.449001, 0.853412, 1.543683,
       1.125591, 0.780225, 0.453074, 0.166888, 0.181113, 0.309359, 0.424315, 0.829189, 1.416077,
       1.128033, 0.781222, 0.452797, 0.16714, 0.180499, 0.303655, 0.477813, 0.833212, 1.387943,
       1.130903, 0.779686, 0.450783, 0.166252, 0.180017, 0.302535, 0.447166, 0.831837, 1.41966]; % 72 elements
CDa_i = griddata (AoA, vel, CDa, -35, 7);
```

So I need to transform every dependent variable (column) into 1D-array size of (NxM) and use `griddata`

This could be done for all columns but the process is tedious and error-prone.

I need somewhat like: [$CDa$, $CLa$, $CSa$, $Cmxa$, $Cmya$, $Cmza$] = interpNxM($AoA$, $vel$);

**The question:** Does a simpler solution exist?

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem, you have two independent variables.  You don't explain what functions of these two variables need to be fitted.  Perhaps your Question isn't about the fitting problems but about data mapping?

Comment: My question is about interpolation of given variables. Yes, I don't want to fit any function. At least I think I don't need it. I would like to get, say [CDa,CLa,CSa,Cmxa,Cmya,Cmza]=interpolation(33,17) from the given table above. I have the solution, but I guess it may be shorter.

Comment: Interp or interp2 should work. I am a bit sick so I can't answer, but you can type help on those or maybe google for tutorial how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the problem, so maybe I am not answering the correct thing.

At least in GNU Octave (which aims to be Matlab-compatible) you can use the function "interp2"

First we create a **meshgrid**, which is a table of coordinates:

```
[xs,ys] = meshgrid(AoA,vel);
```

In our case it is two dimensional, like a matrix or 2 index tensor.

secondly we need list of coordinates where to interpolate:

for example for (AoA = 1, vel = 12),(AoA = 10, vel = 20), we construct:

```
lstXs = [1, 10]; 
lstYs = [12,20];
```

next we feed this to "interp2" function :

```
[interpCDa] = interp2(xs,ys,CDa,lstXs,lstYs);
```

and our interpCDa is:

```
[0.17883,0.18257]
```

The second one, (10,20) we can check, is exactly on a coordinate in the table, so the value should be exactly the same value 0.18257.

Now we can make same similar call for all the other ones, for example:

```
[interpCLa] = interp2(xs,ys,CLa,lstXs,lstYs);
```

will take at same coordinate list lstXs,lstYs in a table CLa.